# how to insert a value on a text field in html using a string from php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

how can i do this properly?

```
<?php
    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personalities
        RIGHT JOIN tbl_video ON tbl_video.personalities_id = tbl_personalities.personalities_id 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language 
        WHERE blablabla";                                           

    $sqlb = "SELECT count(*) as numero FROM tbl_personalities 
        RIGHT JOIN tbl_video ON tbl_video.personalities_id =tbl_personalities.personalities_id  
        LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language 
        WHERE blablabla";   
?>
<input type="text" name="sqlfield1" value="<?php echo $sqla?>">
<input type="text" name="sqlfield2" value="<?php echo $sqlb?>">
```

how can i put the data in the text field in html?

Comment: Ever heard about query execution ?

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you ask.

Comment: firstly, what exactly are you trying to do here? are you trying to add  the sql statement to value? if yes than you are on right track. just dont forget space between '<?pfp' and your variable.

Comment: it should work but you should not do this

Comment: why? i wanna insert the sql statement in the form.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels: you are giving users unlimited access to your database internals, opening your system to SQL injection, and entering a long query in a textfield is terrible - at least use a `textarea` :)

Comment: please just help me insert a value from php to html text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send the queries like that in input elements.Its very dangerous

I can change the value of inputs to `DROP TABLE tbl_video` from firebug.
Then your whole table will be erased from the db

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$extrasql = "";
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personalities RIGHT JOIN tbl_video ON tbl_video.personalities_id = tbl_personalities.personalities_id LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language WHERE ".$extrasql;
$sqlb = "SELECT count(*) as numero FROM tbl_personalities RIGHT JOIN tbl_video ON tbl_video.personalities_id = tbl_personalities.personalities_id LEFT JOIN tbl_language ON tbl_language.language_id = tbl_video.video_language WHERE ".$extrasql;  
?>
<input type="text" name="sqlfield1" value="<?php echo $sqla?>">
<input type="text" name="sqlfield2" value="<?php echo $sqlb?>">
```

Comment: Is this meant as a joke?

Comment: Every code works. The question is: what does it do? And, more important: what was the question? Without knowing what the OP want's to do, what is the point in writing an answer?

Comment: Pls take a look at the title of this post